# Individual/Phenotype representation of an image in GA (divide it in subrectangles)

Tags: image-processing, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to optimize an image with GAs where it is partitioned in complementary rectangles. I wish to set my search space to be all possible partitions.

My main problem about this representation is that I cannot find an "repressentative" crossover operation (If I select a subset of rectangles of each parent, then how should I proceed in cases such as overlapping or empty spaces)

I may find really useful any advise about the typical representation of an image in GAs. (Maybe redefine the problem in another way)

[An example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OftaF.jpg)

[Another example](http://www.hamiltonbuilders.com/images/prod/Hanson/Hanson_Pat_Spiral.jpg)

**Edit 1**:
For mutation I am looking for something that allows me to:

1. Move the limits between rectangles.
2. (If possible) Join rectangles.
3. Split rectangles.

Comment: One option is to NOT do the crossover.  It's an unecessary complication IMHO. Mutation alone is fine.

Comment: If you take away crossover, you're removing the exploitation element of the search. Which sort of defeats the purpose of using machinery like a GA.

Comment: @OP maybe this is one of those problem spaces that doesn't lend itself to crossover/combination easily. Do your rectangles have to cover the entire canvas? Or can it be sparse?

Comment: Yes, they must cover the entire image.

Comment: @Mark How does removing crossover negate exploitation??  Crossover doesn't imply exploitation.